# How is the right funtion pointer found in polymorphic language?

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

Let's say we have this interface in Java-like language:

```java
interface Animal {
  public int getAge();
}

interface Tamable {
  public void tame();
}
```

Those interfaces is being implemented by classes:

```java
class Cat implements Animal { // Cats are not tamable
  public int getAge() {      // this method is somewhere in memory (e.g. at 0xf000)
    // ...
  }
}

class Dog implements Animal, Tamable {
  public int getAge() {      // this method is somewhere in memory (e.g. at 0xf008)
    // ...
  }
  public void tame() {       // this method is somewhere in memory (e.g. at 0xf00e)
    // ...
  }
}
```

When passing interface `Tamable` to some another method like this:

```java
  void pet(Tamable tamable) {
    tamable.tame();          // <-- this call
    // ...
  }
```

How do we know which memory adress to jump to when calling `tame()`? How are VMT (Virtual Method Table) implemented in this case?

The only way I can imagine them being implemted is some hash table, but this seems like it would make virtual dispatch very slow.

If VMT is just array/vector of function pointers, then how does compiler know what offset to use to get function pointer `tame()` on class `Dog`, when dispatching the call, when at compile-time it cannot be resolved whenever `tamable` would be `Dog` or `Cat`?

*(Note: Java was used just as example, I am looking for more general answer)*

Any suggestions would be helpful. All the resources I found on the Internet were very vague about how VMT are implemented and how keys for VMT are gained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each implemented interface an object of class contains pointer to this interface's VMT (so called `vptr`). Whenever you call a function which takes interface as a parameter (like `pet` in your case) a pointer to `vptr` is passed under the hood (`vptr` is not passed directly because compiler will also need to pass location to object when calling interface methods through `vptr`).

Each VMT is just an array of function pointers. The index of each method in this array is statically assigned by compiler based on the order of methods in interface declaration.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly:

The `Dog` class (or instance?) has two `vptr`s, one for `Animal`, one for `Tamable`. The `tame()` declaration in interface `Tamable` has some compiler-assigned offset (e.g. `0`), so when I pass the object `(Dog) dog` into the `pet(Tamable tamable)` function, then not only the `dog` is passed, but also the `vptr` for `Tamable` and then it basically calls `vptr[0]`?

Comment: @MaBed Your understanding is correct except for the "not only the dog is passed, but also the vptr for Tamable" part - in fact a single pointer to `vptr` (not `vptr` itself) is passed. This allows compiler to know both the addresses of methods (though `vptr`) and address of the object data fields (because they are located at known fixed offset from `vptr`).

Comment: Got you, thanks for the answer and for clearification!